# How to encapsulate returning ref to pointer to C_string?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have some C++ code interfacing with 'X' code (as in X11).  For one of the calls it wants to have a param be the address of a pointer to a string.  The call is setup to take a counted array of strings.  In this case, it's only taking 1 string (a winname derived from the hostname).  What is currently in place is something along the lines of:

```
char winname_[257];    // to hold Cstr returned by gethostname()
string windowName{};   // holding string version (prefer strings, but need 
                       // Cstr's for C-compat in places)
```

Have functions:

```
string XWin::WindowName(string name) { 
  if (name.size()) windowName = name;
  if (!windowName.size()) {
    gethostname(winname_, sizeof(winname_)-1);
    windowName = getResourceOrUseDefault(string("title"), string(winname_));
    strcpy(winname_, windowName.c_str());
  }
  return windowName;
}

inline char * winname() {if (!winname[0]) WindowName();return winname;}
```

To pass to the Xfunc, I need:

```
char * winname_p = winname_;
```

As the X function takes:

```
Xfunc(&winname_p, 1, et, al.)
```

What I'd like to do is be able to encapsulate the "winname_p" reference in a function, so I can check that `winname_p[0] != 0`, and have the function return a pointer, but so far, I am flailing in having a function return 
an lvalue so I can have something like:

```
Xfunc(&winname_ptr(),1, et,al.)...
```

I haven't figured out the return syntax for the function so that
it returns an lvalue to winname_p.  I'm sure this is simple for 
many, but I seem to have some blocks when it comes to pointers & functions.

Answer (score 1):

Like many things, this is easy once you know the answer.
Initialize the pointer as a const (to indicate it shouldn't be changed):

```
char  * const winname_p{winname_};
```

Then the wrapper:

```
char * const &XWin::winname_ptr(void) {
    if (!winname_[0]) WindowName();
    return winname_p;
}
```

And the usage:

```
if (XStringListToTextProperty(
    const_cast<char **>(&winname_ptr()), 1, &title_) == 0) {...}
```

Would have been simpler to not use const, but it seems more accurate this way.